# API design and the relevancy of SOLID

Tags: api, domain-driven-design

I am wondering if SOLID is applicable when handling the following usecase.

There are 3 services:

-A consolidator service

-A voucher service

-Financial service ( accountancy )

In a certain scenario the consolidator service needs to get all details of a voucher to
be able to send a payload with all data to a financial service.

In the voucher service there are 2 endpoints which can be used:

- endpoint A only providing the needed properties
- endpoint B (rest) providing the full voucher with the needed properties inside of it.
  The delta in data between the 2 endpoints is not big. We are not handling big quantities of data here.

Now I have a colleague saying we need to use endpoint A because we only need to ask what we need.
I dont agree cause in the future they might need another data prop which will be available if they use endpoint B.

I only have the above two options to choose from now.
I believe the best way is to use endpoint B but then define the needed fields so you only get what you need, by re-using 1 endpoint for N usecases. By allowing the consumer to define the fields needed of a resource....

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

as you said delta in data between the 2 endpoints is not big

so for future work it will be easier to handle changes ( a bit less code with bit low performance  ) when you choose endpoint b.

Comment: Yes, I agree but this is against the SOLID principles because I'm asking stuff I do not need.
I can disregard them of course but that's beside the point.

So I get your answer but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Open for Extension is one of SOLID principle , so its deepens how you see it .

i will choose in this case endpoint b for easy changes and extensions